# Dynamic parameter selection MySQL Stored Procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I apologize if this has been asked (happy to view a previously answered question if there exists). I use a MySQL stored procedure to validate 5 answers in a form a user submits

```
CREATE PROCEDURE schema.procname(
INOUT p_answer1 CHAR(1),
INOUT p_answer2 CHAR(1),
INOUT p_answer3 CHAR(1),
INOUT p_answer4 CHAR(1),
INOUT p_answer5 CHAR(1))
...
...
```

I have a loop that currently execute n times for each question/answer. Once all answers are correct, I write a record. In each iteration I want to change the answer parameter I'm comparing to each question's correct answer. So in pseudo code:

```
LOOP
   
 IF v_correctanswer != **p_answer1**
     -- do stuff --
 IF v_correctanswer != **p_answer2**
     -- do stuff -- 
 IF v_correctanswer != **p_answer3**
     -- do stuff --
```

Is there a way *dynamically* to change the parameter name I'm comparing in each iteration of my loop? I know I can get it to work by manually listing out the conditions (if Q1 then p_answer1, if Q2 then p_answer2) but I don't like the idea of having to specify every condition in case the total # of questions changes in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Start your procedure from the code:

```
DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS tt_answers;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tt_answers (id INT, answer CHAR(1))
SELECT 1 id, p_answer1 tt_answer UNION ALL
SELECT 2, p_answer2 UNION ALL
SELECT 3, p_answer3 UNION ALL
SELECT 4, p_answer4 UNION ALL
SELECT 5, p_answer5 ;
```

Now you may use all answers as ONE rowset, as one more row source in a query.